# Hexagonal lattice and geometry

Tags: geometry

![Hello, first of all thanks for all who take their time to read my question and try to put value out. My question is regarding the hexagonal lattice I posted as image. I extended it by my own but the numbers 11,12,13 & 14 seem to be not correct. That's the first problem that I don't know where and second what are the real distances for the lattice numbers 11, 12, 13 & 14 observed from point 0 regarding the geometry rules?

Best regards.

[image][image]

Comment: What are the numbers supposed to represent? Also, you had this on a computer screen. Was taking a photograph of the screen really the best option you had for getting a picture of your grid?

Comment: Hello, These numbers mark an index j of the distance between an atom in the center and an atom in the respective cell. The distance for 9 is for example squared 19 and the distance to cell 10 is squared 21 but I don't know how they were calculated to use it for the numbers 11, 12, 13 & 14. And yes, not a good idea but for my 2nd question I'll take care to do it better.

Comment: So why is there a $3$ right next to a $1$? Shouldn't that be a 2? What exactly are the rules here?

Comment: I added the part of the paper.

Comment: It's impossible to tell whether the numbers are right if you don't tell us what $r_{11}$, $r_{12}$, $r_{13}$ and $r_{14}$ are.

Comment: Yes, that's right. These cells shall be Xenonatoms regarding my case.

Comment: I have changed my lengths' unit in order to comply with yours.

Comment: Is there also a formula you could share to measure the real distances for clarification purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following representation that I just obtained :

[image]

One can see figures in the cells : they represent exact distances from the origin to the center of each cell (well, rounded to $10^{-2}$).

One can see arcs of circle centered at the origin numbered $1,2,3,...$ : their radii are the different distances one finds on the figure.

Then your labelling follows this logic : a cell is labelled $n$ if the $n$th circle passes trough its center...

For example, the 12 cells at distance $2.65$ from the origin are labelled $4$ because circle n° 4 passes though their centers.

One finds back the first values given in your text :

$$1, \sqrt{3}=1.73, 2, \sqrt{7}=2.65, 3, 2\sqrt{3}=3.46...$$

About your numbering : I am afraid you have to reconsider it...

Comment: Is there also a formula you could share to measure the real distances? For clarification purposes.

Comment: You mean, given an index $n$ be able to say it is at distance $d(n)$ ? Unless consulting the table $d(1)=1, d(2)=\sqrt{3}, d(3)=2,d(4)=\sqrt{7}...$ I don't see immediately a "formula" as such because this indexing relies on previously found distances. I will try...